# Can I $.wrap() around a collection of elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Let's say I have a collection of 'items' like so:

```html
<p class="item">Item 1</p>
<p class="item">Item 2</p>
<p class="item group">Item 3</p>
<p class="item group">Item 4</p>
<p class="item">Item 5</p>
```

I want to loop through the items and wrap a containing div around any that have the 'group' class to result in something like this (grouped items will **always** be right next to one another):

This is the script I've got:

```js
var group = [];

$('.item').each(function(i, item) {
  if ($(item).hasClass('group')) {
    group.push(item);
  }
});

$(group).wrap('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="item">Item 1</p>
<p class="item">Item 2</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="item group">Item 3</p>
  <p class="item group">Item 4</p>
</div>
<p class="item">Item 5</p>
```

What happens is that the wrapping div is wrapped around each element separately in the array (which makes sense) but I need it to wrap all elements together. Is there any way I can do this? Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LanMt/2/).

There is a more complex variation of this problem that is possible, this would be a situation where there are several 'sets' of these groups, each to be wrapped in their own 'group' `div`. Initial state:

```html
<p class="item">Item 1</p>
<p class="item">Item 2</p>
<p class="item group">Item 3</p>
<p class="item group">Item 4</p>
<p class="item">Item 5</p>
<p class="item group">Item 6</p>
<p class="item group">Item 7</p>
<p class="item group">Item 8</p>
<p class="item">Item 9</p>
```

Desired state:

```html
<p class="item">Item 1</p>
<p class="item">Item 2</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="item group">Item 3</p>
  <p class="item group">Item 4</p>
</div>
<p class="item">Item 5</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="item group">Item 6</p>
  <p class="item group">Item 7</p>
  <p class="item group">Item 8</p>
</div>
<p class="item">Item 9</p>
```

Comment: do you only want to group contiguous sets of `.group` elements?  i.e. could you have two groups in a list, which need to be kept separate?

Comment: @Alnitak, you are right to suspect me of holding something from you. This is indeed correct, there can potentially be several 'sets' of groups that are each to be wrapped. I will update my question, but yes, I'm fiddling around with jsFiddle and it's painfully slow...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) method instead:

```
$(".group").wrapAll("<div class='wrap' />");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LanMt/3/

---

For wrapping the separate groups of `.group` elements you can use the following:

```
$(".group").map(function() {
    if (!$(this).prev().hasClass("group")) {
        return $(this).nextUntil(":not(.group)").andSelf();
    }
}).wrap("<div class='wrap' />");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LanMt/5/

The code above was assembled with the help of [@Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11242594/1249581).

Comment: VisioN, I will be using this in my code, please object if there are any issues with CC licensing.  This is super easy and utilizes what I initially loved about jQuery but have strayed away from after learning JavaScript more... that is, the simplicity of single commands stringed together to achieve so much!.  Also, I learned two new methods `.andSelf()` and `.map()` method to produce a `.wrapAll()` effect.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon Glad that you found this useful. Feel free to use the code anywhere you like. BTW, consider using `addBack` instead of `andSelf`, as the latter is now deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Use wrapAll instead of wrap.

```
$(".group").wrapAll('<div class="wrap" />');
```

Documentation of wrapAll can be found at - http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Other wrapping methods available can be found at - http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-around/

EDIT:

For the complex case where there can be more than one groups, we can achieve it using wrapAll with a $.each as follows -

```
var group = [];
        $(".item").each(
          function(i, item) {            
            if ($(item).hasClass("group")) {
                group.push(item);
            }
            else {
                $(group).wrapAll('<div class="wrap" />');
                group = [];
            }
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of `.filter` and `.map` to achieve the desired result:

```
$(".item.group")
.filter(function() {
    return !$(this).prev().is(".group");
})
.map(function() {
    return $(this).nextUntil(":not(.group)").andSelf();
})
.wrap('<div class="wrap" />');
```

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/rA7zS/).

[**Example on JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/amijiq/edit#javascript,html,live) to get around the current JSFiddle problems.

#### Rationale

The method [`.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) embeds *each item* inside the current jQuery object inside the markup of your choice. It follows that if you want to wrap multiple elements in the same wrapper you have to match those N elements with a jQuery object and then create another jQuery object that contains *one* element: the first jQuery object. It is this latter object that you should pass to `.wrap`.

So what we need to do here is create one jQuery object for each group and then put all of those into another "master" jQuery object. Begin by selecting all `.group` elements that are not themselves preceded by a `.group` sibling:

```
$(".item.group")
.filter(function() {
    return !$(this).prev().is(".group");
})
```

From each such element, create a jQuery object that includes the element and all following siblings with `.group`:

```
.map(function() {
    return $(this).nextUntil(":not(.group)").andSelf();
})
```

The resulting jQuery objects are automatically placed inside the "master" object because they take the place of the bare elements we selected with `.filter` inside the jQuery object we created with `$(".item.group")`. A final call to `.wrap`... wraps things up. :)

Comment: It took about 4 years but, kudos to you for the `.wrap()` pun.  I got it! Also, thanks for this awesome answer and explanation.