# How to wrap a group of html elements in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, cheerio

How can I wrap a div tag around all the .firstlevel p tags in a document. Basically creating a parent node for all the firstlevel p nodes and repeat the same process for all the target classes: .secondlevel and .thirdlevel p nodes.

I have tried a few ways based on similar questions in the forum without success.

The resulting document from the current code is not in the needed format.
With the current the div is wrapping around around consecutive p.firstlevel nodes and not around all the p.firstlevel nodes, but I need the div to wrap all the p.firstlevel from start of the document to the end.
The p.secondlevel, p.thirdlevel are all being wrapped properly.

My question is how do I wrap a div starting from the first p.firstlevel to the last p.firstlevel as shown in the desired output?

Below is the code that I adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242430/can-i-wrap-around-a-collection-of-elements-in-an-array):

```
$(".firstlevel")
    .filter(function() {
        return !$(this).prev().is(".secondlevel");
    })
    .map(function() {
        return $(this).nextUntil(".firstlevel").andSelf();
    }).wrap('<div class="wrap" />');
```

Sample source html

```
<p class="generic">Lorem ipsum dolore</p>
<p class="firstlevel">One - Quibusdam, asperiores
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="secondlevel">Two - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="thirdlevel">Three - Pariatur, consequuntur.</p>
<p class="thirdlevel">Three - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="secondlevel">Two - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="thirdlevel">Three - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="thirdlevel">Three - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="secondlevel">Two - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="secondlevel">Two - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Dolor repellendus</p>
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore</p>
```

Desired output

```
<p class="generic">Lorem ipsum dolore</p>
<div class="first">
<p class="firstlevel">One - Quibusdam, asperiores
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<div class="second">
<p class="secondlevel">Two - Lorem ipsum dolore
<div class="third">
<p class="thirdlevel">Three - Pariatur, consequuntur.</p>
<p class="thirdlevel">Three - Lorem ipsum dolore
</div>
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
</div>
<div class="second">
<p class="secondlevel">Two - Lorem ipsum dolore
<div class="third">
<p class="thirdlevel">Three - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="thirdlevel">Three - Lorem ipsum dolore
</div>
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
</div>
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<div class="second">
<p class="secondlevel">Two - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="secondlevel">Two - Lorem ipsum dolore
</div>
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="firstlevel">One - Dolor repellendus </p>
</div>
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore
<p class="class_gen">Lorem ipsum dolore</p>
```

The document structure should not change while wrapping the target p nodes with (.firstlevel, .secondlevel, .thirdlevel, etc.) classes.

Comment: First of all: wrapping <p> in a another <p> is not semantic.
To wrap elements use jQuery.each with selector you need

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: I have adjusted my question to ask what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question for anybody, who might need the same solution or approach. I adapted the solution I mentioned above.

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var fs = require("fs");
var jquery = fs.readFileSync("./js/jquery.js", "utf-8");

jsdom.env({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    src: [jquery],
    done: function(errors, window) {
        var $ = window.$;

    $(".firstlevel").first().removeClass("firstlevel").addClass("firstone");
    $(".firstlevel").last().removeClass("firstlevel").addClass("lastone");

    //Working as expected        
    $(".firstone").map(function() {
        if (!$(this).prev().hasClass("firstlevel")) {
            return $(this).prev().nextUntil(".lastone").next().addBack();
        }
    }).wrap("<div class='wrap' />");

    //Working as expected    
    $(".secondlevel").map(function() {
        {
            return $(this).nextAll(".thirdlevel").addBack();
        }
    }).wrap("<div class='wrap' />");

    //Working as expected    
    $(".thirdlevel").map(function() {
        if (!$(this).prev().hasClass("thirdlevel")) {
            return $(this).nextUntil(":not(.thirdlevel)").addBack();
        }
    }).wrap("<div class='wrap' />");

    console.log($('body').html());
}
```

});

Here is a [working demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/pvugtjye/) on JSFiddle